# Can't Access Bios Toshiba

Tags: bios

I currently have a Toshiba Satellite p205d-s7439 and I set a bios password a while back and can't remember it. I am running Windows Vista 64bit and I tried using the     debug    command in the command prompt and still no change. Is there a CMOS battery I can remove or a jumper I could take out to reset it?

Comment: You would have to take the CMOS battery out. This will also reset all of the other BIOS settings, but you won't lose any other data.

Comment: What backdoor passwords might there be to backdoor it

Comment: You'd have to find out what motherboard is being used in the laptop. Thanks to OEMs using specialised motherboards and/or not filling out the details of the motherboard for utilities like CPU-Z to retrieve, this might prove difficult unless you're willing to open up the laptop.

Comment: I just checked using wmic and my motherboard is a toshiba jasaa

Comment: Contact tech support with proof of ownership. It's the only way.